# Performance difference between a+=b and a=a+b

Tags: c

I know the two statements below give the same results:

```
a+=b; 
a=a+b;
```

In the case of `a += b`, `a`  is evaluated only once while in the case of `a = a + b`, `a` is evaluated twice.

Is there any difference in performance between the two?  If not, are there any variations of the above where there is a difference?

Comment: yeah, the second one involves more typing....

Comment: What difference are you expecting? Difference in what context? Your question is off-topic without those remarks.

Comment: Like  internally process

Comment: What do you mean by *internally process*?

Comment: gcc can translate your code to assembly, then you could analyze difference in assembly code between two operations and answer on your question

Comment: The difference is in 'typing' only. Internally, they are equivalent.

Comment: means which is faster?

Comment: @User123 in typing? the first one.

Comment: Faster in what context?

Comment: In second expression a repeat two time.

Comment: and in the first expression, its one mention serves two purposes. It's the same.

Comment: @User123 :  As to creating an assembler output there are pretty good online compilers, which show us that there is no difference with -O0 set. godbolt.org/g/FSldQD

Answer (score 4):

From the standard (section 6.5.16.2, point 3):

> A *compound assignment* of the form **E1** *op* **=** **E2** differs from the simple assignment expression ***E1 = E1** *op* **(E2)** only in that the lvalue **E1** is evaluated only once.

That is, if instead you are doing

```
*a += 1
```

it will only determine the target location once instead of twice. For "simple" variables as in your example, it might not make much of a difference. Of course, if the compiler knows there is no need to do it twice, it can still optimise and do it once. In case there are other entities that can change the pointer (such as another thread), there is a real difference.

EDIT: Perhaps a better example is something weird like the following (abusing the fact that &b == &a-1 in my case):

```
int a, b, *p;

a = 1; b = 5; p = &a;
*p += (--p == &b) ? 1 : 0;
printf("%d %d\n",a,b); // prints 1 6, because --p happens first, then *p

a = 1; b = 5; p = &a;
*p = *p + ((--p == &b) ? 1 : 0);
printf("%d %d\n",a,b); // prints 1 2, because the second *p is evaluated first,
                       // then --p and then the first *p
```

Comment: @glglgl Yes, the examples are meaningless. And cause undefined behavior for several separate reasons.

Comment: Yes, technically both have undefined behaviour, but that doesn't mean they are meaningless, I'd say. Simply doing a+b can result in undefined behaviour. I doubt many programmers add checks to make sure all goes well in such cases. In the context of a specific compiler, I think the example does a good enough job of illustrating the difference between the two forms. Of course, better examples are always welcome.

Comment: Can have isn't the same as does have. If you present a self-contained example that is supposed to show a point, it better be correct.

Comment: Also, statements: *because --p happens first, then *p*, and: *prints 1 2, because the second *p is evaluated first,
                       then --p and then the first *p* are blatantly wrong.

Comment: Yes, they are wrong in the general specification of C, but not in the context of the specific system I'm using (as evidenced by the actual code generated by the compiler). I believe we've already established this and you have made your point.

Answer (score 1):

`a+=1` is probably the best way to go (However the difference in performance  is almost insignificant). You should look up for other parts of your code if you are trying to achieve some performance improvements.